# Collection view Repeating user selection

Tags: c#, .net, maui

am new to .net maui applications.  I have a problem where I have a collection view where a user selects from a radial button group or enter data.  I have the 2 data templates in the resource dictionary.  Everything works as expected, However when a user clicks on a button as you scroll down the selection they made appears as the new rows get rendered in.  I am not sure why this is happening.  Anyone can help would be greatly appreciated.

User clicks on the first 2 rows:

[image]

Scrolling you can see 2 in a row have been selected while user did not click they just scrolled down the list. This repeats every 6-7 rows down.

[image]

View:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckField">
            <Frame Padding="10" Margin="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="5" HasShadow="True" StyleClass="FrameBorderBig" BorderColor="Transparent" IsVisible="{Binding ShowMe}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height=".1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height=".9*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions ColumnDefinitions=".4*,.2*,.4*"/>
                    <!--Equip title-->
                    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <Label x:Name="EquipLabel" Text="{Binding EquipName , StringFormat='Equipment - {0}'}" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="{Binding HexColorForLabel}" />
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                    <!--Left side -->
                    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Label x:Name="SubEquipLabel" Text="{Binding SubEquipName,StringFormat='Sub Equipment Name - {0}'}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label x:Name="ItemNameLabel"  Text="{Binding ItemName,StringFormat='Main Equipment Name - {0}'}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <RadioButton VerticalOptions="Center" GroupName="{Binding UniqueGroupName}" Value="LooksGood" x:Name="LooksGoodRad"  CheckedChanged="OnRadioButtonCheckedChanged"/>
                            <!--<CheckBox VerticalOptions="Center" CheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged" x:Name="LooksGoodCK"></CheckBox>-->
                            <Label x:Name="LooksGoodLabel" Text="Looks good" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Label.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference LooksGoodRad}, Path=IsChecked}"
                                                 TargetType="Label" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="DarkGreen">
                                        </Setter>
                                        
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Label.Triggers>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <RadioButton  VerticalOptions="Center" GroupName="{Binding UniqueGroupName}" Value="Problems"  x:Name="ProblemsRad" CheckedChanged="OnRadioButtonCheckedChanged"/>
                            <!--<CheckBox VerticalOptions="Center" CheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged" x:Name="ProblemsCK"></CheckBox>-->
                            <Label Text="Problems" VerticalOptions="Center"  x:Name="ProblemsLabel">
                                <Label.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference ProblemsRad}, Path=IsChecked}"
                                                 TargetType="Label" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="DarkGreen">
                                        </Setter>

                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Label.Triggers>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                    <!--Right side-->
                    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,50,0">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <RadioButton VerticalOptions="Center" GroupName="{Binding UniqueGroupName}"  Value="offline" x:Name="offlineRad"  CheckedChanged="OnRadioButtonCheckedChanged"/>
                            <!--<CheckBox VerticalOptions="Center" CheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged" x:Name="OfflineCK"></CheckBox>-->
                            <Label Text="Offline?" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="OfflineLabel">
                                <Label.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference offlineRad}, Path=IsChecked}"
                                                 TargetType="Label" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="DarkGreen">
                                        </Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Label.Triggers>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="InputField">
            <Frame Padding="10" Margin="0,0,0,0" CornerRadius="5" HasShadow="True" StyleClass="FrameBorderBig">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height=".1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height=".9*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions ColumnDefinitions=".4*,.2*,.4*"/>
                    <!--Equip title-->
                    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <Label Text="{Binding EquipName , StringFormat='Equipment - {0}'}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                    <!--Left side -->
                    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Label  Text="{Binding SubEquipName,StringFormat='Sub Equipment Name - {0}'}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label  Text="{Binding ItemName,StringFormat='Main Equipment Name - {0}'}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label  Text="{Binding LowerLimit,StringFormat='Lower Limit - {0}' }" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label  Text="{Binding LowerRange,StringFormat='Lower Range - {0}' }" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label  Text="{Binding UpperRange,StringFormat='Upper Limit - {0}' }" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label  Text="{Binding LowerLimit,StringFormat='Upper Range - {0}' }" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                    <!--Right side-->
                    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,-15,50,0">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="End">
                            <RadioButton VerticalOptions="Center" GroupName="{Binding UniqueGroupName}"  Value="offline"  x:Name="offlineRad" CheckedChanged="OnRadioButtonCheckedChanged"/>
                            <!--<CheckBox VerticalOptions="Center"></CheckBox>-->
                            <Label Text="Offline?" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Label.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference offlineRad}, Path=IsChecked}"
                                                 TargetType="Label" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="DarkGreen">
                                        </Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Label.Triggers>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="Enter data" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                            <Entry Placeholder="Data" Text="{Binding Data}" Margin="15,0,0,0" Keyboard="Numeric" MinimumWidthRequest="200" Unfocused="OnEntryUnfocused" BindingContext="{Binding .}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
        <TempSel:DataSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector"
                              CheckField="{StaticResource CheckField}"
                              InputField="{StaticResource InputField}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<!--Main grid -->
<Grid Margin="15" RowDefinitions=".1*,.3*,.7*">
    <Label Text="Daily check list" StyleClass="BoldHeader" Margin="10,0,0,0"></Label>
    <!--First Row grid -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" RowDefinitions=".2*,.8*">
        <Label Text="Floors" StyleClass="MedHeader" Margin="12,0,0,0"></Label>
        <CollectionView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Floors}" SelectionChanged="OnFloorSelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single" >
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="5" Orientation="Horizontal"></LinearItemsLayout>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <RoundRectangle StyleClass="FloorsRectangle"/>
                        <VerticalStackLayout Padding="15" Spacing="10">
                            <Label StyleClass="CardTitle" Text="{Binding Tasks, StringFormat='{0} Tasks'}"></Label>
                            <Label StyleClass="CardTitle" Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                            <ProgressBar Progress="{Binding Percentage}"></ProgressBar>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
    <!--Second grid -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" RowDefinitions=".2*,.8*">
        <Label StyleClass="BoldHeader" Text="Checklist Item"></Label>
        <CollectionView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentShowingList}" x:Name="CheckListItems" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}" ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="1" ></LinearItemsLayout>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

CodeBehind:

```
`public partial class DailyCheckList : ContentPage
{
private DailyCheckListViewModel model = new DailyCheckListViewModel();
public DailyCheckList()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = model;
}
private void OnFloorSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FloorsAndTasks CurrentList = (FloorsAndTasks)e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault();
    model.LoadDailyChecklistItems(CurrentList.Name,model.TotalCurrentTaskPending);

}
// this for the entry of data
private void OnEntryUnfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{

}


private void OnRadioButtonCheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{

}

private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var ck = sender as CheckBox;
    var stackLayout = ck.Parent as StackLayout;
    var form = stackLayout.BindingContext as CheckForm;
    var parentFrame = ck.GetParentOfType<Frame>();
    foreach (var child in stackLayout.Children)
    {
        if (child is Label label)
        {
            var labelText = label.Text;

            if (ck.IsChecked)
            {
               
            }
            else
            {
                // re-enable checkboxes.
            }
        }
    }

}
}`
```

VM:

```
class DailyCheckListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<CheckForm> CurrentShowingList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CheckForm> TotalCurrentTaskPending { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<FloorsAndTasks> Floors { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public DailyCheckListViewModel()
    {
        FillData();
    }

    public void LoadDailyChecklistItems(string floor, ObservableCollection<CheckForm> TotalCurrentTaskPending)
    {
        List<CheckForm>  ShouldShow = TotalCurrentTaskPending.Where(x => x.AreaName == floor).ToList();
        foreach (CheckForm checkForm in ShouldShow) 
        {
            checkForm.ShowMe = true;
        }
        CurrentShowingList = new(ShouldShow);
    }


    private void FillData()
    {
        var LocaStoreDaily = App.DailyRepo.GetItems().Where(x => x.CheckDate == DateTime.Today).ToList();
        var codes = App.CodeTableRepo.GetItems().OrderBy(x => x.Sequence).ToList();
        var CurrentForms = App.FormRepo.GetItems().ToList();
        TotalCurrentTaskPending = HelperSan.RemoveSavedCheckListItems(CurrentForms, LocaStoreDaily, 1);
        TotalCurrentTaskPending = HelperSan.AddNamesToIDs(codes, TotalCurrentTaskPending);
        int completedCount = TotalCurrentTaskPending.Count(x => x.Completed);
        int totalCount = TotalCurrentTaskPending.Count;
        float percentage = 0;
        if (totalCount != 0)
        {
            percentage = (float)completedCount / totalCount;
        }
        List<FloorsAndTasks> test = TotalCurrentTaskPending.GroupBy(x => x.AreaID).Select(g => new FloorsAndTasks
        {
             ID = g.Key,
             Name = codes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Code == g.Key && c.Field == "Area")?.CodeName ?? "",
             Tasks = g.Count(),
             CompletedTasks = completedCount,
             Percentage = percentage,
        }).ToList();
        Floors = new (test);
        Debug.Write("Done logic");
    }

}
```

Comment: I suspect the data trigger is confused by the fact that the same `x:name` exists in each use of the DataTemplate. Might work better if you add to project a new ContentView named CheckFieldView, with that xaml in it. Then DataTemplate simply contains `<mynamespace:CheckFieldView ... />`.

Comment: What's the code of `CheckForm`,`FloorsAndTasks`?  If it is convenient for you, could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Hello thank you both for taking the time to respond.  Looks like I managed to make a work around.  I would have liked to have given the user a green font as a feed back but I removed that trigger.  I also added a binding to the isCheck for each of the radial buttons.  The only thing that happens now is the checkChange event is firing off when you scroll and the rows are being de-rendered or rendered if the user scrolls up back to one they have selected.  I appreciate both you guys help.  I would like to spend time to fix it the right way but sadly I need to move on as deadlines are looming :(